# Add a last edited by column to find content results

Tags: nodes, users

In the admin area when a user is on the find content page /admin/content I would like to add an extra column to the results table to display the user who last edited the node.

I'm fine with actually querying to get the data I'm just not sure of the best way to add the extra column to the results table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking [Extra Columns](https://drupal.org/project/extra_columns)

> This module allows additional columns/data to be added to the node,
>   comment, and user tables in administration area. It provides a list of
>   fields defined in your drupal installation as well as a few custom
>   fields to choose from.

Alternatively you can try [Administration Views](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module.

[image]

Comment: I have Admin Views installed already. I've just installed Extra Columns, enabled extra columns for /admin/content form but when I go to that page I don't see the Add Extra Columns button

Comment: Go to admin config and click extra columns and set it, check this https://drupal.org/files/project-images/3_0.PNG

Comment: I've already ticked the boxes to enable extra columns on the three forms. Cleared my cache. Checked the permissions, I'm logged in as admin. But still no joy.

Comment: go to chosen form(e.g. /admin/content)
Click on the Add Extra Columns button and choose which fields you want to display

Comment: That's where it all goes wrong. There is no button to Add Extra Columns. I've even viewed source and searched for it in case it was somehow hidden by something else.

Comment: Yaa I tried, look like bug in module, if you have time submit to issue queue.

Comment: This is incorrect. Extra Columns module does not give the option to add an "Edited by" column. "Administrative Views" is the answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/109785/27767

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [Administration Views](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views)

1. Install the module

   - Enable it
2. Edit "Administration: Nodes" view

   - Add a Relationship

     - Select "Content revision: User"
     - Name it "editor"
   - Add the field to the view

     - Select "User: Name"
     - click "Apply (all displays)"
     - Under relationship, select "editor"
     - Change Label to "Edited-By"
     - click "Apply (all displays)" again
   - Save the view

**Note:** The "Extra Columns" module does NOT give the option to add an "Edited by" column. Also, The Admin Views module is incompatible with Extra Columns module (only one will show up at a time)